# SharedUserId & Files

Tags: android

Can `sharedUserId` provide access to files in the data/data/com.example/files dir?

I tried to do that, and I can retrieve the context and check if this dir is exists, although when I trying to read files from it the debuger gives me PERMISSION DENIED error.

[They say](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html) in documentation that `SharedUserId` provides shared access to **data** and even can run two apps in the same process, what is the data about what they are saying? Can it be that this feature gives only access to 'static' resources of the application and not to the ones that have been created dynamically?

**UPD**

```
fw_context = createPackageContext("com.example", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
String[] str = fw_context.getFilesDir.list();//str=null
```

As I have commented, the `str` here is `null`, I don't know why it's `null`, but I know that there is some files in this dir (I have rooted phone so I can see this)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can sharedUserId provide access to files in the data/data/com.example/files dir?

Yes, if and only if:

- Both apps have the same non-empty `sharedUserId` value
- Both apps have *always* had the same non-empty `sharedUserID` value (i.e., you cannot update an app from not having `sharedUserId` to having a `sharedUserId`)
- Both apps are signed by the same signing key

That being said, `sharedUserId` is almost never the right answer, for the simple reason that neither app will know about what the other app is doing with the files. Use a `ContentProvider` (or some other form of IPC) to share content between apps, using `signature`-level permissions or other identity checks to ensure that only the right apps can interact over the IPC channel.

Comment: Thank you for answer! I have read your previous answers on that subject and already decided that I can't use this feature in my case, but I'm still trying to understand why if someone can do that, why I can't! I added implementation of getting the context and how I'm trying to get list of files, it's always null, and if I try with single file with exact address it says PERMISSION DENIED, and my  case is complied with the conditions that you have outlined.

Comment: @MovsarBekaev: I'd start by logging what `fw_context.getFilesDir()` returns and confirm that it looks to be correct.

Comment: The `File f = fw_context.getFilesDir();` returns correct path to the /files/ dir of com.example application, anyway, I spent a whole day for that and only now came to know that I can't use this even if it works, so I try to learn about FileProvider, I just need to copy files from one app to other, and don't want to use external permissions, as people have very negative attitude to downloading such apps.. thank you once more, and thank you for the book, it will be very useful to study it!